# Pandas individual item using index and column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file test.csv. I am trying to use pandas to select items dependent on whether the second value is above a certain value. Eg

```
index  A     B
0      44    1
1      45    2
2      46    57
3      47    598
4      48    5
```

So what i would like is if B is larger than 50 then give me the values in A as an integer which I could assign a variable to

edit 1:

Sorry for the poor explanation. The final purpose of this is that I want to look in table 1:

```
index  A     B
0      44    1
1      45    2
2      46    57
3      47    598
4      48    5
```

for any values above 50 in column B and get the column A value and then look in table 2:

```
index  A     B
5      44    12
6      45    13
7      46    14
8      47    15
9      48    16
```

so in the end i want to end up with the value in column B of table two which i can print out as an integer and not as a series. If this is not possible using panda then ok but is there a way to do it in any case?

Comment: Daniel, I deleted my answer since it wasn't what you wanted.  Please consider updating your question with more details and/or an example of your desired output.

Comment: Ok I am sorry I didn't provide enough detail I'll update it now please let me know if its better

Comment: Hows this? If you have any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, Bob's answer returned you the values as a series, assigning to the values conceptually makes no sense how can you assign to 46 and 47, they are integer values in a Series? You can hold the Series as a variable but if you want to assign to those row's then you can use `loc` which is what Bob answered

Comment: For clarity, it can help to show the exact results you want (values, new column names, etc.)  You could just take the table you already have above and add the new column with the desired values.

Comment: Yeah, that's better, though it's not clear why you want integers rather than a series.  A series can hold a group of integers, and you can always extract a single integer from a series or dataframe in a variety of ways (e.g. with `ix()`.  So it appears your results are 2 integers (14 and 15) corresponding to values of A (46 and 47).  Normally you'd collect the 2 integers in something (list, series, dataframe)

Comment: thats what im missing i dont know how to extract the integer

Comment: in: `df.ix[0,'A']` out:`44`    in: `type(df.ix[0,'A'])` out:`numpy.int64`

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataframa [slicing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html), to get the values you want:

```
import pandas as pd
f = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')
f[f['B'] > 50].A
```

in this code

```
f['B'] > 50
```

is the condition, returning a booleans array of True/False for all values meeting the condition or not, and then the corresponding A values are selected

This would be the output:

```
2    46
3    47
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Your answer was already posted and deleted by Bob Haffner, (you can't see it as you don't have enough rep), the OP needs to clarify exactly what they are after